# The easiest way to get hotswap ability while using kotlin-to-js transpiler?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

What is a easiest way / tools / technologies to get hotswap ability, while coding HTML (kotlinx-html-builder) and pure javascript (kotlin-to-js) using kotlin & gradle & IDEA ?

Not very desirable to use create-react-kotlin-app (since i'm coding pure simple js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution currently, but one of the way to go is kotlin to js cli:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line-library-js.html

so you can implement some file system listener and recompilation step via cli mentioned above.